# how to call graphql resolver inside go code

Tags: go, graphql

I tried this code

```
url := "http://142.77.221.41:8000/graphql"
query := `{
     hello(theme:"HELLO WORLD", html: "<h1>hello</h1>", recipientList: "hello@mail.ua") {theme, html, recipientList} 
}`

body := strings.NewReader(`{"query":` + query + `}`)
//json := `{"query":` + strconv.QuoteToASCII(query) + `}`
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, body)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(resp.Status)
```

it sends

> 500 Internal Server Error

but when I go to the http://142.77.221.41:8000/graphql and type the same query on playground it works fine

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug this?  For instance, you're telling the server you're posting an HTML form; does that match the examples on graphql.org or the actual data you're sending?

Comment: compare requests details in browser network tab